# Evaluate formula stored as string in bigquery

Tags: string, date, google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery which has a column storing different date formulas like DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 1 DAY),DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 7 DAY) as per the requirement in different rows.I want to use this table to compute end_date in a different table using these formulas.In this current table the column type is string.Is there any way I can compute the formula in bigquery which is stored as string in another table?

Comment: how vary these formulas can be? are they relatively static and the only what changed is a number of days for intervals? or they can be pretty much anything so you are looking for sort of generic evaluation?

Comment: Yes,the formulas may vary a lot.So, I am looking for a generic evaluation.

Comment: i can guess of course, but can you provide few more examples of such in-string stored formulas?

Comment: and what would be the logic of when to use which formula (as you mentioned there are many different - so you need to know which one and when to use) would be great if you can write pseudo code for this to illustrate this. The reason I am asking is that I want to show you how easy this can be done with one of the product I have created - meantime, you can check some product videos and documentation -  https://potensio.zendesk.com

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle *arbitrary* expressions, consider storing your formulas as Javascript expressions. Then you can use a JS UDF and eval() to resolve them at query execution time.

Don't forget to put a try-catch around them (and return NULL or some sort of error record) -- otherwise your entire query will fail if someone enters an invalid expression somewhere.

To pass information between your eval'd expression and the UDF wrapper, you can just use globally scoped variables.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions

You might also consider making a table-driven expression resolver, if you have a limited set of distinct expressions. That might map a string like LAST_WEEK to the actual value for NOW() - 7 days, etc. A CASE statement should suffice for this.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#conditional-expressions